# CFM redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, coldfusion, http-status-code-301

On Google I have a site that has a bunch of old links to its pages, they are links like this.

```
 /mainpage.cfm?linkId=84&LinkType=mainlink
```

I want to 301 redirect them with htaccess, but nothing I am trying works.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/architectural
RewriteRule .* /mainpage.cfm?linkId=84&LinkType=mainlink
```

Any Ideas, I have tried many varients of this, it seems the problem is the .cfm file.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit fuzzy.  You say you want to rewrite *from* `/mainpage.cfm?linkId=84&LinkType=mainlink`, but then you also have that as the *target* of your RewriteRule.  So I think some wires are crossed somewhere.  Can you please update your question to include "I want to rewrite [this current URL example] to [the URL you wish the first one to end up at]".  Also any other considerations that might require a RewriteCond, and any variations in the patterns.

*Then* we can get your rules/conditions sorted out.

To answer your exact question as asked, your RewriteCond will reject `/mainpage.cfm?linkId=84&LinkType=mainlink` because that does not match `^/architectural`.

However I suspect this is *not* the question you mean to ask...

Answer (score 0):

in mod_rewrite RewriteRule can only see the directory and file part of the URI and not the query string. So to match the query string you need to use RewriteCond.

e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}            linkId=(\d+)&LinkType=mainlink [NC]
RewiteRule ^mainpage\.cfm              newpage.php?linkid=%1 [NC,L]
```

I have matched the linkId in the RewriteCond which I then refer to by %1 in the RewriteRule as this is the syntax for matching groups in a RewriteCond.

As @AdamCameron points out you don't state where you want to redirect to, but this should give you the tools to resove it.

Answer (score -1):

You could perform the redirect within the ColdFusion page instead.  Just add the following line to the top of the mainpage.cfm file (assuming you want every request of that page redirected).  You could add some condition logic if you only want to redirect specific `linkId` and/or `LinkType` based on the URL parameter.

Again, if you want every request to the mainpage.cfm to redirect just add this to the top of that file (**NOTE** you need to change the url for the redirected page):

```
<cflocation url="http://host/architetural" statusCode="301" addtoken="no">
```

*The statusCode attribute was added in ColdFusion 8 - so you must be running that or newer*

Comment: Thanks but I dont have the cfm site enywhere, the site is gone, I just need for the apache on the new site to not redirect the old links under the same domain name

Comment: If they have .htaccess available (the correct tool for the job), suggesting doing it on the app server (not the correct tool for the job) is a bad suggestion.